# Haskell difficulty with type signature for a variable

Tags: haskell, typeclass

```
tuple :: (Integer a,Fractional b) => (a,b,String)
tuple = (18,5.55,"Charana")
```

So this is giving me the error

```
‘Integer’ is applied to too many type arguments
In the type signature for ‘tuple’:
tuple :: (Integer a, Fractional b) => (a, b, String)
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 7):

Integer is a concrete type in Haskell, whereas Integral is a typeclass used to denote things which can be represented as an integer.  As such, you could choose to write:

```
tuple :: Fractional a => (Integer,a,String)
tuple = (18,5.55,"Charana")
```

or

```
tuple :: (Integral a,Fractional b) => (a,b,String)
tuple = (18,5.55,"Charana")
```

Answer (score 4):

`Integer` is just a type.

```
tuple :: Fractional a => (Integer, a, String)
```

Or maybe you meant to use `Integral a`?